# What is the distribution of $\frac{1}{2}[(X_1 - X_2)^2 + (Z_1 - Z_2)^2 + (Z_1 + Z_2)^2]$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be a random sample from normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $X_1$ and $X_2$ be a random sample from normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(1, 1)$. Suppose the $Z_i$'s are independent of the $X_j$ 's. Note that $Z_2 - Z_1$ is independent of $Z_1 + Z_2$ and similarly $X_2 - X_1$ is independent of $X_1 + X_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What do you know about Chi-squared distributions?

Comment: Hi Robert Israel, I did some derivation. I got $\(X_1 - X_2)^2$ is  $\mathcal{N}(0, 2)$, and same for $Z_2 - Z_1$ , $Z_1 + Z_2$. Let W = $\mathcal{N}(0, 2)$, then it is $\frac{3}{2} W^2$, then we can say it is Chi-squared distributions? is it right? Thanks

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael, sorry above comment have a typo, I got $X_1 - X_2$ is $\mathcal{N}(0, 2)$